# How to read specific string object from JSON string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

How to get specific value from this JSON string. I want to get nested nested JSON object `"FromUserId": "bd079f57"` and pass it to Javascript function.

```
"notification":{
       "title" :"Test",
       "message" : "Message",  
           "android": {
                 "data": {
                         "priority": "2",
                        "profile": "profile",
                        "message": "xxx has sent you a Message.",
                        "style": "inbox",
                        "noteId": "1",
                        "visibility": "1",
                        "title": "Test",
                        "badge": "12",                  
                        "FromUserId": "bd079f57"                            
                        }
                    }
                 }



 "onNotification": function (notification) {         
                        var obj = JSON.parse(notification.message.android.data.FromUserId);  
                      // How to pass this test.FromUserId to ReadData function.                     
                      ReadData(obj)
                    }
$scope.ReadData(obj){
 //further process of json
}
```

Comment: var obj = JSON.parse(test);
ReadData(test.notification.android.data.FromUserId);

Though im not 100% sure your json is valid, I assume it isn't actually set out like above.

Comment: Are you getting string ? if yes then parse it like `JSON.prase(_your_json)` and then `notification.android.data.FromUserId` ?

Comment: JSON.parse(notification.FromUserId) should be JSON.parse(notification)

Comment: I dont understand why people are down voting this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below :

```
"onNotification": function (notification) {         
                        var test = JSON.parse(notification);
                        var obj= test.notification.message.android.data.FromUserId;  
                      // How to pass this test.FromUserId to ReadData function.                     
                      ReadData(obj)
                    }
$scope.ReadData(obj){
 //further process of json
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify` converts a JavaScript data structure into a **string**.

`test.FromUserId` attributes to read the `FromUserId` property of an **object**.

It isn't clear what the input to your function is, but you need to either:

1. (If you are passing an object): Forget about JSON entirely. Remove all your JSON related functions. *or*
2. (If you are passing a string of JSON): Use `JSON.parse` only, and use it only on `notification`.

Then you need to access through *each layer* of your data structure. You can't ignore all the objects between the top level and your data.

i.e. You need `notification.message.android.data.FromUserId` not `test.FromUserId`.

(In case 2 replace `notification` with `test` but you'll still need to explicitly access the `message.android.data` layers).

Comment: `test.FromUserId` would be `undefined` as `test` is a string.

Comment: @George — `test` won't be a string if the instructions in this answer were followed.